# Pass repeated row values to an array in excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, vlookup

I have a table like below in excel,

```
Hub Depend
a   b
a   c
b   d
b   e
b   f
c   g
c   h
d   i
d   j
f   k
h   l
h   m
m   o
```

I need to extract Hubs and Depends to array like this

```
(b,d) and (b,e) and (b,f).
```

my code is:

```
For i = 2 To lastrow
sid = Cells(i, 1).Value
res = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sid, Sheet1.Range("A:A"), 2, False)
Next
```

but when i use VLOOKUP it only gives me (b,d) and doesn't process after finding first match.

Comment: What you want is to get and array this way: myArray() `===>` myArray(1) = (a,b), myArray(2) = (a,c)

Comment: yes, exacxtley, but i dont know if vlookup can do this or not speacially using VBA

Answer (score 0):

Well, hope this could help you:

```
Sub SinaNouri()
    Dim i As Range
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim c As Integer 'just a counter
    Dim myArray()
    Set rng1 = Range("A2:A14") 'the range of the first column

    c = 0
    For Each i In rng1
        c = c + 1
        ReDim Preserve myArray(1 To c)
        myArray(c) = "(" & i.Value & "," & i.Offset(0, 1).Value & ")"
    Next i
End Sub
```

Note

`myArray(#)` will have text (`Strings`) not numbers. If you want to handle numbers use this:

```
Sub SinaNouri()
    Dim i As Range
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim c As Integer 'just a counter
    Dim myArray()
    Set rng1 = Range("A2:A14") 'the range of the first column

    c = 0
    For Each i In rng1
        c = c + 1
        ReDim Preserve myArray(1 To c)
        myArray(c) = i.Value & "," & i.Offset(0, 1).Value '!!!!!!
    Next i
End Sub
```

And `myArray(#)` use it with Split, this way `Split(myArray(2), ",")`. The you remove the comma, and get only the numbers to use it as you need.